# Is there a way to power up PC by lan? [Win 10]

Tags: wake-on-lan

I have the server turned on all the time in the office's LAN. Others PC are turned off after regular workday. I want to remotely boot one of the PC from my home. I can use the remote desktop connection to the server. Is there a way to power up a PC by sending some packets in LAN?

I've followed several tutorials, like this one: https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-use-wake-on-lan-on-windows-10/ but I was able to wake PC only if it was sleeping/hibernating.

Is it even possible to power on turned off PC by LAN? Is it a hardware matter?

Comment: "Is it even possible to power on turned off PC by LAN?" Yes. See [What Is Wake-on-LAN, and How Do I Enable It?](https://www.howtogeek.com/70374/how-to-geek-explains-what-is-wake-on-lan-and-how-do-i-enable-it/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant wake a system thats been fully shutdown. If WOL is available comes down to hardware support, the power state of the system your trying to wake and the ability to send the "magic" packet to the target systems NIC. If your able to wake up sleeping systems but not shutdown systems i think you already have your answer. Heres what Microsoft have to say...

> WOL is supported from sleep (S3) or hibernate (S4). It is not
>   supported from fast startup or soft off (S5) shutdown states. NICs are
>   not armed for wake in these states because users do not expect their
>   systems to wake up on their own.
>
> NOTE: WOL is not officially supported from soft off (S5). However, the BIOS on some 
>   systems may support arming NICs for wake, even though Windows is not involved in the 
>   process.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-states

Couple of options that come to mind:

- change how you shutdown the system / live with the minimal power consumption of the machine in standby/hibernation instead of completely off.
- If you must keep the system shutdown as you currently do, maybe a "smart" plug or other IoT device could allow you to power up the system remotely instead of WOL?